# bryntum component integration

Tags: php, extjs, schedule, zoho, bryntum-scheduler

I am trying to integrate the bryntum component(schedule) in php. I am not much aware in ext js.
Please see the images [here](http://fgtpl.com/fugenx1/public_html/stackoverflow/bryntum.png)

Here, Name fields are fetching properly, whereas Capacity is not accessing. These values are coming from Zoho CRM.
My code is like [Click](http://fgtpl.com/fugenx1/public_html/stackoverflow/demo.zip), whereas r-read.php file is the responsible file for fetching the record from CRM and store it in a json format. It is like

```
{
    "success": true,
    "total": 9,
    "root": [{
        "Id": 1,
        "Name": "Sri Test",
        "Capicity": "190.0"
    }, {
        "Id": 2,
        "Name": "tester_test01",
        "Capicity": "500.0"
    }, {
        "Id": 3,
        "Name": "Tesing room 23",
        "Capicity": "5000.0"
    }, {
        "Id": 4,
        "Name": "Test for 6th product",
        "Capicity": "5000.0"
    }, {
        "Id": 5,
        "Name": "Banquet hall test-01",
        "Capicity": "500.0"
    }, {
        "Id": 6,
        "Name": "test room",
        "Capicity": "1000.0"
    }, {
        "Id": 7,
        "Name": "Grande Ballroom",
        "Capicity": "4000.0"
    }, {
        "Id": 8,
        "Name": "Cedar Room",
        "Capicity": "1400.0"
    }, {
        "Id": 9,
        "Name": "Maple Room",
        "Capicity": "1200.0"
    }]
}
```

In the capacity column, it will show like 190.0 , 500.0, 5000.0 etc like Name column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familier with the Bryntum schedular component, but most of the time when you have problems like these it's because you didn't define the `Capacity` field in your model.

I saw you used the following model: `Sch.model.Resource`. Can it be that is only has the `Name` field and not `Capacity`? Your JSON response looks fine to me.

Comment: But I didnt understand how to define capacity? Could you please help me?

Comment: First of all I did not modify anything except App.js and PHPScheduler.js file.
Even I did not understand the flow of this ext js. So I didnt understand how to show the Sch.model.Resource model.

Comment: Ok, I think you'll have to create your own model with a Capacity field in it. But as I sayd, I've never used Bryntum schedular so I'd mail their support first.

Answer (score 0):

In the sample JSON above, **Capacity** is spelled `Capicity`.

See if the same spelling needs can be used everywhere. Maybe then the data will resolve properly.